# HTML/CSS Navigation Bar Not Being Responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I am having trouble with my Navigation Bar being responsive. The links within the Nav Bar keeps breaking out etc. I am using flexbox...Well trying too but not sure what the problem is.

Everything else on my website is working fine, but it's the navigation bar that is not working properly. Whenever I try to resize the browser, the links come closer to one another but eventually breaks out and then the last link disappears. I will post a sample below and also on CodePen.

I've been messing around with the code, trying to figure out what is happening and why it's not working as everything else on my website is but i've come to a dead end and Stack Overflow seems to be my final stop -sadface- Thanks for any information!

**CodePen -** https://codepen.io/vCoCo/pen/NoYYRW

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<header>
  <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href""><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
/*** GLOBAL VARIABLE ***/
body{
  background: #000;
}

.container{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
/*** GLOBAL ENDS **/

header{
  max-width: 600px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}

header li{
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

ul li a:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve but if you want to make all elements visible as the screen becomes smaller (and not being cut off) you could use the `flex-wrap: wrap;` property. Add it to your `ul` and it will allow the flex items to wrap into a new line if the screen gets too small.

This is your provided codepen with the additional property
https://codepen.io/vCoCo/pen/NoYYRW

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is stemming from the fact that you have not removed the default padding:

```
header ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

if you would like them to all be on their own line you can add flex wrap as newbiedude suggested or change flex-direction to column.  Depending on your desired output.  Let me know how it goes.